# Fill NAN if previous record found in a combined dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following Dataframe:

```
  Country   Client_id     Order_date
0   USA          aaa1       1/1/2020
1   CA           bbb2       2/2/2020
2   JP           ccc3       2/2/2020
3   USA          aaa1       3/10/2020
4   NaN          aaa1       1/9/2020
5   NaN          bbb2       20/5/2021
6   NaN          ccc3       20/5/2021
7   NaN          ccc3       20/5/2021
```

I have many NaN in the country columns, but each client_id has in the previous first rows is assigned to a country. So, I need to match each client_id for NaN rows with previous rows, if value found so NaN replaced with the correct country.

The expected output:

```
  Country   Client_id     Order_date
0   USA          aaa1       1/1/2020
1   CA           bbb2       2/2/2020
2   JP           ccc3       2/2/2020
3   USA          aaa1       3/10/2020
4   USA          aaa1       1/9/2020
5   CA           bbb2       20/5/2021
6   JP           ccc3       20/5/2021
7   JP           ccc3       20/5/2021
```

What I did so far is sorting by client ID so they will be arranged and then fill the country:

```
df.sort_values(df['Client_id']).groupby('Country').ffill()
```

but this did not work for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try

```
df.Country.fillna(df.groupby('Client_id')['Country'].transform('first'),inplace=True)
df
  Country Client_id Order_date
0     USA      aaa1   1/1/2020
1      CA      bbb2   2/2/2020
2      JP      ccc3   2/2/2020
3     USA      aaa1  3/10/2020
4     USA      aaa1   1/9/2020
5      CA      bbb2  20/5/2021
6      JP      ccc3  20/5/2021
7      JP      ccc3  20/5/2021
```